# javascript example add remove element

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I am struggling with javascript these days, I want to create dynamic add/remove element using java script and i came across following site, but following example doesn't working for me do you know what is wrong in example?

[Adding and Removing Elements on the Fly Using JavaScript](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2007/07/adding-and-removing-elements-on-the-fly-using-javascript/)

I am having issue in following line, which i found using chrome developer tool

```
var html = '<input type="file" name="uploaded_files[]" /> ' +
               '<a href="" onclick="javascript:removeElement('file-' + fileId + ''); return false;">Remove</a>';
```

Here is the screenshot of google chrome developer tool

[image]

Comment: And that issue would be ... what?

Comment: 'doesn't working' isn't exactly something we can help you with. Be more specific. Any error messages?

Comment: What is `file-` and why is it outside the quotes?

Comment: @Baszz - I have edit my question with `screenshot`

Comment: If you are doing lots of DOM manipulation (adding/removing elements) you should consider jQuery. There are lots of tutorials online (check google). Furthermore, you should try to move away from inline javascript, to improve readability and avoid issues like you have here with escaping quotes etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your quotes.

`var html = '<input type="file" name="uploaded_files[]" /> ' +
               '<a href="" onclick="javascript:removeElement(\'file-\' + fileId + \'\'); return false;">Remove</a>';`

Comment: Thanks! it works :) but when i add more than 2 element and delete two it remove rest of elements.. is that a normal behavior?

Comment: It really depends how you have coded the removal function. There is no reason properly written code should do things you don't want it to!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to escape those single quotes.

```
 onclick="javascript:removeElement(\'file-\' + fileId + ''); return false;">Remove</a>';
```

That is what I would try.

You want the quotes to be there when you add the text.
You will also have a have files that are named like this

```
  file-1
  file-2
```

Comment: Don't forget the other single quotes.

Comment: @Johnb - Not working error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string`

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `addElement('files', 'p', 'file-' + fileId, html);`

At the end of addFile()?

We can't do anything for you if we don't have more information about your 'problem'

Be more explicit in your description.